# Fetching parent value from child from json

Tags: javascript, json, jsonpath

I have the following json and I am trying to get the `requestId` based on the value we have in `teamId`.

I am trying with json path

```
$.[*].teamAssignments[?(@.teamId == 'Team:144')]..
```

for the this json:

```
[
  [
    {
      "requestId": "56cd284767c74d3d4dd3ec81",
      "role": "Software Engineer",
      "roleName": "Software Engineer",
      "teamAssignments": [
        {
          "teamId": "Team:144",
          "teamName": "ABC!",
          "teamFactoryNumber": "123",
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
]
```

Is there a way I could retreive the `requestId` from `teamId` value ?

Comment: Are you sure you want to use a technology which was not updated in the last 10 years (on first glance at least?)? According to the info on the site linked inside the tags, I could only say that the [`parent`](http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/) path isn't supported

Comment: the other option i can try is to write javascript to fetch the parent

Comment: That might be a lot easier ;)